# What does this bash command do?

Tags: bash, scripting

What does this command do? Can it be shortened without losing functionality?

```
echo "abcabcabc" | sed "s/aBc/xyZ/gi;s/Z/a/;s/c/CCC/g" | xargs ls -ld
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you could just run the command and see what it does.

Answer (score -1):

You would know what the command does if you entered it on a Mac OS terminal. It doesn't do anything but producing an error because the i in the sed command seems to be wrong or a typing error. However

`echo "abcabcabc" | sed "s/aBc/xyZ/g;s/Z/a/;s/c/CCC/g" | xargs ls -ld`

outputs the string abcabcabc which is used as input for the sed command which replaces aBc with xyZ, Z with a and c with CCC. This results in the string abCCCabCCCabCCC which is again input for the ls -ln command. If you had a file with the name abCCCabCCCabCCC in the current directory it would be found and it's details would be shown to you, otherwise the output is

```
ls: abCCCabCCCabCCC: No such file or directory
```

If it could be shortened depends on what you really want to achieve.

`echo "abcabcabc" | sed "s/c/CCC/g" | xargs ls -ld`

would have the same result in this case.

Comment: The `i` modifier is a GNU extension
     which makes `sed` match in a case-insensitive manner (also supported by Perl).